# I can't get this code to work to make an object float when hitting a trigger in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a golf game in Unity and am trying to make it so when the ball enters a cylinder it floats upwards, here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class LevitationCylinder : MonoBehaviour
{
    // This is the force that the ball is going to be shot up with when it hits the cylinder.
    public float UpwardsForce = 10f;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        // Check if the object that entered the trigger is the ball and not any of the obstacles.
        if (other.CompareTag("Ball"))
        {
            // Get the Rigidbody component of the ball and make sure it's found.
            Rigidbody rb = other.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            if (rb != null) 
            {
                // Add a force to the ball in the upward direction.
                // The force should be contstantly applied becayse of acceleration mode.
                rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * UpwardsForce, ForceMode.Acceleration);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried hitting the ball into the cylinder and was expecting it to go upwards, however, nothing happened. It just passed completely through the cylinder.
I have the tag set as "Ball" on the ball object and I have the "Is Trigger" boxed checked on the cylinder but it just does not work and doesn't even show any errors. I have also tried increasing the force but this does not work.

Comment: Well. By the sounds of it get the thing to acknowledge it was triggered. Then worry about how hard and how you add force.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the inner if statement is getting executed? i.e. add a `Debug.Log` inside it? If not, check if you've actually added the LevitationCylinder component to the Cylinder object. 
Lastly, I'm assuming you're in a 3D project? Otherwise you should be using the `OnTriggerEnter2D` method instead. I've mixed those up a few times.

Answer (score 0):

actually the force being acceleration would only be updated per frame if it had na void Update. In this case, it only calls the first frame of the acceleration, making some movement imperceptible.
So it's better to apply another force method, like ForceMode.Force.